# Android Studio Design View Missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

An update came in for Android Studio today so I updated it BUT now the BUILD and TEXT buttons aren't on screen. Current version I'm running is 3.6.2. Can anybody please help me I've an assignment due for next week

Comment: Can you tell detail and put please any screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

They have been moved, use the three buttons on top right of the screen.

[image: Buttons at top right]

Comment: Thank you so for that.  If I ever see you in really life I'll buy you a bottle of vodka